# How do I answer 你家有几口人？他们是谁？

Tags: translation

My homework is asking about my family but the question after asks about what they do. How do I answer the question of who are they?

Comment: 我家有七口人，爸爸，妈妈，哥哥，姐姐，弟弟，妹妹和我。
this is what we teach our novice A class.

Answer (score 1):

The question was "How many people are there in your family? Who are they (besides yourself)?

Example: 我家只有一口人, 那就是我.

Comment: Is it allowed to ask help for homeworks? I'm not sure.

Comment: This is a new contributor, so perhaps s/he does not know and should be directed to the rules. But long time contributors should know better than to do other people's homework for them.

Comment: Teacher: Did you do this? Student: Yes. Teacher: How come it's traditional Chinese?!... CAUGHT!

Comment: As a beginner, these kinds of questions are great for me.  Pinyin is helpful as my vocabulary is still growing

Answer (score 1):

For example: 我家有五口人，我们是我父母，我妹妹，我哥哥还有我。I think you should just say how are they related to you.

Comment: "我家有五口人，我父母，我妹妹，我哥哥还有我." Or  "我家有五口人，除了我, 其他四口是我父母，我妹妹，还有我哥哥."